# javascript LET variable - why getting undefined and not error when logging before initializing variable?

Tags: javascript

I know there are many many posts on const/let but I couldn't find anything that answered my question:

To my knowledge variables declared using let, are being hoisted to the top but not initialized with undefined like with var, so they create a temporal dead zone until initialized.

In the example below, I log undefined. Why is it undefined if  my console log comes before initialization and why don't I see a reference error?

```js
let x;
console.log("x: ", x)
x = 1;
```

```
//without x= 1 it would be undefined too
```

EDIT

```
let x; 
console.log("x: ", x)
```

will be READ eventually EXACTLY SAME AS

```
console.log("x: ", x); 
let x = 1
```

Comment: You got the explanation wrong - the *initialisation* step is done at the time you reach `let x` - the `x=1` is the *assignment* step. These are two different thins. You'd be in the temporal dead zone if you had `console.log("x: ", x)` as the first statement before `let x`

Comment: Note that "temp." in that quote is "temporal" not "temporary". "temp" is usually a shortening of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

That description of hoisting and the dead zone is about a different situation:

```
console.log("x: ", x);
let x = 1;
```

That's treated as if the `let x;` appeared at the top. However, the `console.log()` in this case *would* give an error, because it appears between the "virtual" position of the declaration and the initializer.

In your case, the `let x;` has no initializer, so `x` can be used anywhere after the declaration. And there's nothing special about the `x = 1` statement; it's just another reference (well, an assignment) to `x`.

Comment: I'll add a personal note that the terminology is in my opinion a little overly dramatic.

Comment: Ah so its all about hoisting - variables declared using let that ARE HOISTED create temp. dead zone until initialization AND variables created before using them / which are NOT hoisted do NOT create dead zone and ARE initialized automatically with undefined ?!

Comment: @javascripting right, and what's important is the fact that the declaration has an initializer. In most code, the error won't happen; it's meant to trap uncommon situations that `var` doesn't catch. Mostly things like shuffling code around can lead to the error (in my experience).

Comment: @javascripting don't confuse initialisation with assignment. The initialisation step makes a variable *usable*. Before it's initialised you cannot use it in any way. Hence the temporal dead zone - you try to use an unusable variable. The *assignment* is a different thing and the `undefined` from before the assignment is just a by-product of having a variable that you can use but haven't assigned yet.

Comment: Its just confusing because both examples (in my question and in answer would be eventually be same): let x;
console.log("x: ", x) will be READ EXACTLY SAME AS console.log("x: ", x);
let x = 1; because here let x will get hoisted to top (not initialized) so does the javascript compiler check: is variable hoisted - if yes through an err, if not hoisted and declared, not initialized, initialize it with undefined ?! PS. edited my question and put both codes there to see better then in here

Comment: @javascripting I agree that it's confusing, but that's the way it worked. The actual placement of the `let` statement is what determines the "dead zone" range.

Comment: @javascripting you are still confusing what hoisting is. It will *not* move `let x` "effectively" to the top. This was a useful description for back when there was only `var` but it doesn't work at all with `let`. Check [this article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/variables-lifecycle-and-why-let-is-not-hoisted/) for a more in-depth look but there are three steps in `let x = 1` - declaration, initialisation, and assignment. Declaration just takes up `x` as identifier. Initialisation is what makes it usable. For `let` *only* the declaration is hoisted, for `var` declaration+initialisation

Comment: @VLAZ so in all cases (var and let) the variable IS actually BEING initialized with undefined when declared, only difference is that with let only the declaration is hoisted and with var both. But in the following example: console.log(x); var x = 1; I would get undefined because using var because ONLY declaration is hoisted (not 1) so what do you mean with : var declaration+initialisation ? Thank you !

Comment: @javascripting initialisation and assignment are different things. So a variable isn't being initialised "with undefined", it's being *initialised* and it *doesn't have a value*. And by "declaration+initialisation" I meant that when you have `console.log(x); var x = 1`  both the declaration *and* initialisation are hoisted - that's why you can *use* the variable before reaching the line with `var` - because it's initialised. With `console.log(x); let x = 1` *only* the declaration is hoisted, therefore you cannot use the variable until it's initialised - using it results in an error due to TDZ.

Answer (score 1):

"let x" declares a variable but hasn't assigned it a value yet. According to Mozilla's JavaScript docs - "A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type undefined." hence the value of 'x' before it has been assigned a value is 'undefined'.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz

> While inside the TDZ, the variable has not been initialized with a value, and any attempt to access it will result in a ReferenceError. The variable is initialized with a value when execution reaches the place in the code where it was declared. If no initial value was specified with the variable declaration, it will be initialized with a value of **undefined.**

Answer (score -1):

you actually are in the temporal dead zone.
temporal dead zone for a is the time period between the a is hoisted and it been initialized.
so when you console.log(a) it is in the temporal dead zone

Comment: If they were in temporal dead zone they would get ReferenceError.